# Nodejs accessing nested variable in global scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

How would I access socket in the global scope based on my following NodeJS code

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log('connection '+socket)
    socket.on("data",function(d){console.log('data from flash: ',d);});
    socket.emit("message","wtfwtwftwftwf hello from server");
    socket.on('disconnect', function (socket) {
        console.log("disconnect");
    });
```

});

I need to access socket from within the following app.post method

```
var express = require('express'),
multer  = require('multer');
var app = express();

//auto save file to uploads folder
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}))

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
console.log(req.body); //contains the variables
console.log(req.files); //contains the file references
res.send('Thank you for uploading!');
});
```

app.listen(8080);

Haven't tested yet but going to try a simple getter function first

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('connection '+socket)
        socket.on("data",function(d){console.log('data from flash: ',d);});
        socket.emit("message","wtfwtwftwftwf hello from server");
return{
getSocket: function(){
return socket;
}
};
        socket.on('disconnect', function (socket) {
            console.log("disconnect");
        });

});

io.getSocket() ??
```

Comment: This is almost certainly the X/Y problem: You want to do X, but you've asked about Y (using `socket` at global scope). What's X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express's `app` and Socket.io have nothing to do with one another.

So fundamentally, you can't use `socket` inside `app.post`.

You need to identify the client. You can use [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) which has a [Socket.io plugin](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio) that essentially bridges the `app.post`/`get`'s `req.user` to `socket.request.user`.

Note: It doesn't have to be an *authenticated* client with user that's fetched from database, just a client with a temporary user stored in memory would do. Something like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) { // if a user doesn't exist, create one
        var id = crypto.randomBytes(10).toString('hex');
        var user = { id: id };
        req.logIn(user);
        res.redirect(req.lastpage || '/');
        return;
    }
    next();
});

var Users = {};
passport.serialize(function(user) {
    Users[user.id] = user;
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserialize(function(id) {
    var user = Users[id];
    done(null, user);
});
```

Then you can attach the client's socket ID to its user session.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.request.user.socketid = socket.id
});
```

And then instead of `socket.emit` use `io.emit` in `app.post` using the `socketid`

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    io.to(req.user.socketid).emit('whatever');
});
```

Note: `io.to()` is used to emit to a **room**, but every socket is by default joined to the same room named as its `socket.id`, so it'll work.

Comment: Thanks!! Even is this doesn't work it seems so well thought out I had to accept it as correct;)

Comment: Would app.post('/', function (req, res) be changed to app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local') ?

Comment: @eco_bach Checkout the updated answer. And no, `passport.authenticate` is only for logging/authenticating users. It expects a `req.body` with credentials so it would most definitely not be used in your main route.

Comment: please see my alternative answer below

Answer (score 0):

Javascript and socketIO experts > please tell me why this simple solution shouldn't work. It seems to...

1 Define a global pointer

```
var _this=this;
```

2 In my socketIO handler make a reference to the socket object

```
_this.socket=socket;
```

3 And finally within app.post, access the socket like thus

```
_this.socket.emit(....
```

Comment: `socket` object is unique for each client that connects. If you make it global then the global object will only refer to the `socket` object of the ***latest*** client that connected. Surely you don't want that.