# Use nested variable from another file

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am working with node.js in visual studio code. Still new to both.

I am trying to call a nested variable with child properties from one js file to use in another file. How can this be done?

I have already referenced the source file in my target file and I am able to call to the file and method that contains the variable which return object.object in console.log. Any calls to the variable itself or to the object assigned to its value come back undefined. I have tried using exports.var but visual studio code does not recognize the command. The object assigned to its value does have an initial global declaration in the source file.

job and its children is the value I want to transfer over. Console.log command in source file does display the expected values.

Source File: dataHandler.js

```
let jobArray = null;

export function getJobDetails() {

if(_jobDetails == null) {
    let job, jobIndex, regIndex;

    regIndex = _productTypes.indexOf("reg");
    jobIndex = (regIndex > -1) ? regIndex : 0;
    job = _jobsData[jobIndex].details;   
    jobArray = job;    
  }
  console.log(jobArray.orderId); //returns expected value

  return _jobDetails;
}
```

Target File: geo.js

```
import * as DataHandler from './dataHandler.js';

export function createGeo() {

    var site = DataHandler.jobArray.orderId;
    //var site = DataHandler.getJobDetails().jobArray;
    //var site = DataHandler.getJobDetails(jobArray.orderId);
```

Comment: Why is the function in one file called `getJobDetail` and another `getJobDetails`?

Comment: Because I was shortening the names for the purposes of the post and left off the 's'. I have edited the post so it will not cause any more confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like following.

```
const DataHandler = require('./dataHandler');
var test = DataHandler.getJobDetail();
console.log(test.orderId);
```

& DataHandler should do something like following. Here important point is I'm returning jobarray from getJobDetails.

```
var jobArray = null;

var getJobDetail = () => {
    jobArray = {
        orderId: 1
    };
    return jobArray;
};

module.exports = {
    getJobDetail
};
```

Comment: Your method worked although I did not need to use the second part for returning jobArray. I am guessing that since orderId is also associated with _jobDetails which is returned, that is why returning jobArray was not needed?

Comment: @MapinTX, I have just used it for demo. You can return anything that serves your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Express's `app` and Socket.io have nothing to do with one another.

So fundamentally, you can't use `socket` inside `app.post`.

You need to identify the client. You can use [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) which has a [Socket.io plugin](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio) that essentially bridges the `app.post`/`get`'s `req.user` to `socket.request.user`.

Note: It doesn't have to be an *authenticated* client with user that's fetched from database, just a client with a temporary user stored in memory would do. Something like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) { // if a user doesn't exist, create one
        var id = crypto.randomBytes(10).toString('hex');
        var user = { id: id };
        req.logIn(user);
        res.redirect(req.lastpage || '/');
        return;
    }
    next();
});

var Users = {};
passport.serialize(function(user) {
    Users[user.id] = user;
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserialize(function(id) {
    var user = Users[id];
    done(null, user);
});
```

Then you can attach the client's socket ID to its user session.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.request.user.socketid = socket.id
});
```

And then instead of `socket.emit` use `io.emit` in `app.post` using the `socketid`

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    io.to(req.user.socketid).emit('whatever');
});
```

Note: `io.to()` is used to emit to a **room**, but every socket is by default joined to the same room named as its `socket.id`, so it'll work.

thanks : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310418/nodejs-accessing-nested-variable-in-global-scope

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning "jobArray", Use Promise to return the variable to your child file.